# Exclude a directory from `ls -R` command in FreeBSD

Tags: command-line, bash, freebsd, ls

I want to list all of my files in a directory in FreeBSD 9.2, but I don't want to include a specific directory. I checked both `-I` and `--ignore` parameters for `ls`, but `I` only ignores superuser mode and `--ignore` is not supported.

Does anyone have an idea how to use `ls` or do that using another command (like `grep`)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to list all the files except those within a certain directory, say, `notHere` you can use the `find` command to do it like

```
find . -path ./notHere -prune -o -type f -print
```

**Explanation:**

- `.`: the directory to start the `find` in
- `-path ./notHere`: start a rule that will match the path `./notHere`
- `-prune`: prevent `find` from descending into the directory with the current match
- `-o`: add an `or` to specify what we want to happen if the first rule did not match
- `-type f`: match only files, not, say, directories (remove this if you want to see the directory entries as well)
- `-print`: often not needed as it's the default action, but some versions of `find` still want you to expressly say that you want the result to be printed out

You mention wanting other output (specifically `ls -ll`) than just the list of file names.  `find` often has a builtin to help with that, though not those specific options to `ls`.  You could replace the `-print` flag above with `-ls` and see if that set of `ls` options is close enough for you:

```
find . -path ./notHere -prune -o -type f -ls
```

or if that isn't good enough, you could have `find` run the command you want instead of trying to process the output separately like:

```
find . -path ./notHere -prune -o -type f -exec ls -ll {} +
```

Comment: I didn't mention that I need file information, therefore your answer is the answer! However, what I must do to get each file's information such as size and date? (I need an output like `ls -ll`. I know I can feed the find result to a shell script containing a `while`, but I think it would be very slow.

Comment: Many versions of `find` even have a `-ls` that you could use in place of `-print`.  Freebsd's man page says `-ls` will give output like `ls -dgils` which might be close enough for you.  Otherwise you could replace `-print` with `-exec ls -ll {} +` which should be faster than trying to process all the output manually with a `while` loop

Comment: That's exactly what I want. However I cannot +1 yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use this script to filter out all folders with names starting with '_'. It probably won't work with folders that have spaces but you could amend it.

```
#!/bin/sh

A=`ls /j/ | xargs | sed 's/_[a-z0-9]*//g' | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
W=`echo $A | wc -w | tr -d '[[:space:]]'`
echo $W
```

In general the part that's interesting is this:

```
ls some_folder | xargs | sed 's/_[a-z0-9]*//g'
```

The regex `_[a-z0-9]*` contains the pattern to match against the name that should be excluded.

This is if you want list folders without the `-a` option (just names). If you want to use `-a` then the simplest is:

```
ls -la | grep -v skip_folder
```

where `skip_folder` is the name that you want to exclude. Use quotation marks if the folder contains spaces, e.g.:

```
ls -la | grep -v "skip folder"
```

Comment: `ls -la | grep -v "skip folder"` only omits the directory name, and its content remains. I even used `ls -ll | pcregrep --color -v -M "directoryAddress(\n|.)*nextDirectoryFullAddress"`, which omits the whole listing. However, I don't consider this a good answer, because the directory structure may change (i.e. another listing may be added between them) and some data is lost.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, do you want to list directories recursively? If you want to list all files in all directories apart from one then the best for that is `find` since you can grep out specific names based on the path, e.g.: `find . | grep -v .ssh/id_rsa`